# Basic question on Plain Vanilla Interest Rate Swap pricing

Tags: interest-rate-swap, bootstrapping, bootstrap

I'm new to quant and would like to understand on pricing **AUD Plain Vanilla Interest Rate Swap**. In post/article/book often explain for **long end**, we use **SWAP RATE** that are observed in market. But I'm still confused by:-

1. How we can calculate/price a **2Y SWAP RATE** while we trying to price a **2Y Swap**? (This question extends to tenors more than 2Y too)
2. In some books/article, it mentioned we can replicate *IRS* by using liquid Government Bonds?
3. If point (1) is how market works, it means I will need to get those 2Y IRS rates from market (eg: Bloomberg Composite?)

*Edit: To add reference I was using when research on how to do price IRS.*
https://ebrary.net/9371/business_finance/long_end_curve_interest_rate_swaps

Hope questions are clear enough, thank you.

[image]